# React Native AsyncStorage getAllKeys infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

This AsyncStorageHooks react custom hook

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const AsyncStorageHooks = (key, value, mergedValue, keys) => {
 const [data, setData] = useState('');
 const [error, setError] = useState('');

 const storeData = async () => {
   try {
     if (key && value) {
       const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
       await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, jsonValue);
       setData(jsonValue);
     }
   } catch (e) {
     setError(e);
   }
 };

 const getData = async () => {
   try {
     if (key) {
       const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
       setData(jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : '');
     }
   } catch (e) {
     setError(e);
   }
 };

 const mergeData = async () => {
   try {
     if (key && value && mergedValue) {
       const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
       const mergedJsonValue = JSON.stringify(mergedValue);
       await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, jsonValue);
       await AsyncStorage.mergeItem(key, mergedJsonValue);
     }
   } catch (e) {
     setError(e);
   }
 };

 const removeData = async () => {
   try {
     if (key) {
       await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
     }
   } catch (e) {
     setError(e);
   }
 };

 const getAllKeys = async () => {
   let allKeys = [];
   try {
     allKeys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
     setData(allKeys);
   } catch (e) {
     setError(e);
   }
 };


 return {
   data,
   storeData,
   getData,
   removeData,
   mergeData,
   getAllKeys,
   error,
 };
};

export default AsyncStorageHooks;
```

this is my home component

```
 const {data, error, getData, storeData, getAllKeys} =
    useAsyncStorage('@word');
  getData(); // this is works and use setData
  storeData(); // this is works and use setData
  getAllKeys();
  console.log(data);
```

this works without any problems, they use the same page in the same state. It doesn't go into an infinite loop. The only getAllKeys dosen't works. Other functions works without any problems.

**also side note:** setData(allKeys); change to setData(allKeys + ''); or setData(JSON.stringify(allKeys)); stop to infinity loop why is that

Comment: Down voting as this is not an infinite loop and is rather a lack of React fundamentals. As @yousoumar implies, React is calling this function on every state change as it has been improperly implemented. Take an hour reading the "main concepts" page and get the basics down: reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html Trust me, it'll save you hours if not days of trying to figure out simple concepts such as this.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an infinite loop because `getAllKeys()` is being called again and again. The first time it is called, there is this `setData(keys)` being called, which re-renders the component, because there is a state change.

When the component re-renders, `getAllKeys()` is called again, so `setData(keys)` is called, and it goes for ever. You would wanna use a `useEffect` to solve this problem, like so:

```js
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const getAllKeys = async () => {
      let keys = [];
      try {
        keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        setData(keys);
      } catch (e) {
        // read key error
      }
    };
    getAllKeys();
  },[])

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>hi</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I asked the question wrong, I've corrected it now, can you answer it please?